# How to show '&' in Latex?

Tags: latex

I used & to show the R&D acronym in Latex, but it is displayed like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbeKV.png)
How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that shows how you set up your acronyms?

Comment: For future reference, there's [version of the site for TeX an LaTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote from the `acronym` package documentation:

> If the acronym requires problematic or complicate TEX stuff (font commands, . . . ), then this code can be given in the optional argument ⟨short name⟩. The first argument ⟨acronym⟩ is then a simpler string to identify the acronym.

So in your case you can use `\acro{RD}[R\&D]{...}` to avoid the problem with `\&`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}
\begin{document}

Text \ac{RD}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{RD}[R\&D]{\emph{Research and Development}}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

[image]